# the class chrome_omniboxView is no longer available?

Tags: .net, winapi, google-chrome, ui-automation

```
FindWindowEx(Hwnd, 0, "Chrome_OmniboxView", Nothing)
```

Chrome_OmniboxView, is no longer available. how can i get current url of google chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a Chrome extension to resolve this exact problem. I've put it in the chrome webstore (free) here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/add-url-to-page-title/ghpeimfjbonkimelnkbgekmcboomkgmi

All it does is to convert the html title of the page to this format:
Original Title |url:[http://www.the-url.com]

This is put into the window title by Chrome, which you can read using NativeWIN32.GetWindowText(handle);

Comment: How do you get the URL?

Comment: Thanks Simon, however the extension only updates url on page load, and some apps change urls and titles using javascript (gmail for instance). And once they do - url is lost. Can you update the extension to trigger title update on url/title change and on tab focus in addition to page load?

Answer (score 0):

Run Spy++ to figure out the proper class names and window handles you need.  You should have it installed assuming you have Visual Studio installed.

With it, you can point at the window, see the hierarchy of window handles, and the exact class name you should use with `FindWindow()`/`GetWindow()` API calls.

Comment: Spy++ does not show any class name for the url text box (Omnibox)